# How to verify if a method is called on an impl of interface

Tags: java, junit

Here is a scenario

```
public class MyService{

    public void method1(){
        method2();
    }

    private void method2(){

        List<Providers> providers = Factory.getProviders(selectionCriteria);
        providers.forEach(provider->{
            provider.method();
        })

    }
}
```

How do I verify `provider.method()` is called?

note: 
Factory holds a mapping of selection criteria to List.
Providers implement an interface and provide implementation of the abstract method
I have staticly Mocked Factory using PowerMock but when I use Mockito.verify(provider).method() - I get failure

> SetUp
>   @Spy provider1
>   PowerMockito.when(Factory.getProviers(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(provider1))
>
> ```
> Test Code
> ```

Mockito.verify(provider,Mockito.times(1)).method()

Comment: can you please post the test code too? Reduce to a minimal case so it's short enough to post here.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments on your question.  You should [edit] your question instead, and add any additional information that you deem helpful to answering it.

Comment: I have updated sample code in questions.

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to verify behavior docs](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockito#how-to-verify-behavior) the syntax would be:

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic(Factory.class); 
Factory.getProviders(selectionCriteria);
```

Comment: Hi, I am able to verify that static method on factory got called but I also wanted to verify if method on provider got called i.e provider.method().